# Automatically add a Standard Price Book Entry after creating product

Tags: lightning, pricebook, pricebookentry

I am successfully importing a CSV of products and creating Product objects in Salesforce.  I'd like to be able to automatically (or even via CSV update) create Standard prices for those objects, but *without* the step of downloading the products to get the Salesforce ID of each product.

My product codes are unique and I was hoping to be able to look up the Salesforce ID for a product via the Product Code.

I am using Salesforce Essentials so I don't have access to the API.  Is this possible, or do I have to do a multistep process:

- Download all Product2 objects into a CSV (called products).
- Create a new CSV called products_prices.
- For each product:

  - Get Salesforce ID, get price from my database.
  - Create a new CSV record in products_prices
- Upload products_prices using dataloader.io

I am so hoping there is a shorter way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the secrets:

- upsert on the Price Book Entries table is not permitted.  So you must do an insert for new products (without pricing) and an update for existing products (with prices).
- mapping differs on insert and update.  On insert, you want to map product ID.  For me, since I didn't want to download the salesforce product ids, I mapped my unique product code to product ID.  On update, you want to map Price Book Entry ID.  Again, I used the product code to lookup this value.

Comment: Hey Scott can you share some of the code. I am having the same issue. Much appreciate.

Comment: If you go to https://github.com/scottcwilson/zencart_to_salesforce I share all my code and instructions.